# iOS Swift :Object mapper conditional mapping

Tags: ios, swift

I am new at swift , using object mapper for mapping, how can I map if message  key is array in json or string it always return string. 
**Json Reponses**

> {   "error": {
>       "code": 404,
>       "messages": "message"   } }
>
> {   "error": {
>       "code": 406,
>       "messages": [
>         "message"
>       ]   } }

**My Class**

```
class Response : NSObject, Mappable {

    var code : Int?
    var data : AnyObject?
    var message : [String]?


    required init?(map: Map) {

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        code <- map["code"]
        data <- map["data"]
        message <- map["messages"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom Transform for transformations like this.

Create a class, that conforms to the `TransformType` protocol:

```
class ErrorMessagesTransform: TransformType {
    func transformFromJSON(_ value: Any?) -> Array<String>? {
        if let value = value as? String {
            return [value]
        }
        if let value = value as? [String] {
            return value
        }
        return []
    }

    func transformToJSON(_ value: Array<String>?) -> String? {
        // TODO: If needed
        return nil
    }
}
```

Then in your mapping function just do:

```
func mapping(map: Map) {
    code <- map["code"]
    data <- map["data"]
    message <- (map["messages"], ErrorMessagesTransform())
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, save my day